# Can't pull values from dataframe with df.iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

I am using gspread to automate a data entry aspect of my job. Is there any way to pass values from df.iterrows to spreadsheet.values_append?

'Key' looks like:

('Saddle Soap 2.8 oz', 'B01NBEGPNF')
('Bick 4 8oz', 'B001CS2Q4M')
('Saddle Soap 6.5', 'B016DQQYVI')

I am trying to loop through each product with it's corresponding id.

```
key = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Documents/AtomProjects/Sheets1/AutoKey.csv')



#Inputs and file read
print('Date?')
datecolumn = input()
print('Report Path?')
reportpath = input()
df = pd.read_csv(reportpath).drop(columns=['(Parent) ASIN','Title','SKU']) #, index_col = '(Child) ASIN')
#dateinsert
df.insert(0, 'Date', datecolumn)


for index, row in key.iterrows():
    spreadsheet.values_append('Product', params={'valueInputOption':'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': df[(df['(Child) ASIN'] == 'Child')].values.tolist()})
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbook/Documents/AtomProjects/Sheets1/Ukinv.py", line 34, in 
spreadsheet.values_append('Product', params={'valueInputOption':'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': df[(df['(Child) ASIN'] == 'Child')].values.tolist()})
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 164, in values_append
r = self.client.request('post', url, params=params, json=body)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 73, in request
raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Unable to parse range: Product', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}

Thanks so much for checking it out!

Comment: What is the current error?

Comment: @noah Hi thanks, I edited the post to include the current error.